# How to take incremental backup for firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to take incremental backups for firestore? We need to take regular backups and taking full backup everyday will only get more expensive over time.
Also is there any plan of supporting point in time restore for firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore does not have a backup mechanism.  It has an [import/export mechanism](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import), which is not really the same thing.  If you need backups, especially incremental backups, you will need to implement that yourself or find another solution.

Comment: Thanks Doug! Backup/Restore is a very important feature for a database and it's difficult to use Firestore for enterprise applications without this critical feature. Building custom solutions for backup and restore only increases the development time which goes against the idea of Firebase making app development fast. Can't think of any other database which doesn't provide backup and restore feature.

Comment: You are free to leave your feature request with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support